# ¿Cómo pasar variables de un archivo javascript a un archivo php por archivos?

Tags: javascript, php

Necesito visualizar las variables que estoy pasando por `fetch(url)`

La estructura es: al abrir mi sitio web se me muestran los productos disponibles y solo muestro la foto su nombre y unas 3 a 4 características; utilizo la foto y el nombre como enlace para que en otra página se muestre información complementaria del producto y he reservado un `<div id="relacionados>` para mostrar los productos relacionados en forma de tarjetas en un carrusel.

el documento `javascript` que contiene la función que me obtiene unos datos y los almacena en el `locaStorage` y abre la página donde solo se ve información relacionada al producto específico se llama lip.js y tiene:

```
function clave(e) {
   if(!e) e = window.event;
   let id = e.target.id;
   let x = id.split(",");
   let cat = x[0];
   let categoria = cat.replaceAll(" ","_");
   let subcat = x[1];
   let subcategoria = subcat.replaceAll(" ","_");
   let nom = x[2];
   let nombre = nom.replaceAll(" ","_");
   let precio = x[3];
   let clave = "";
   let claveAux = {'aux':'PRODUCTOS/'};
   if (subcat == "--------------------") {
      clave = "PRODUCTOS/"+categoria+"/"+nombre+"/info.json";
      claveAux = {'aux':'PRODUCTOS/'+categoria+'/'};
   } else {
      clave = "PRODUCTOS/"+categoria+"/"+subcategoria+"/"+nombre+"/info.json";
      claveAux = {'aux':'PRODUCTOS/'+categoria+'/'+subcat+'/'};
   }
   let cod_prd = x[4];
   localStorage.setItem("codPROD",cod_prd);
   localStorage.setItem("nombrePROD",nom);
   localStorage.setItem("categoria",cat);
   localStorage.setItem("subcategoria",subcat);
   localStorage.setItem("precio",precio);
   localStorage.setItem("clave",clave);
   localStorage.setItem('claveAux', JSON.stringify(claveAux));
   window.open("producto.php","_self");
}
```

el javascript que esta relacionado a producto.php se llama producto.js y tiene:

```
window.onload = cargar();

function cargar() {
   cargarData();
   cargaSimilares();
}
function cargarData() {
   let aux = localStorage.getItem("clave");
   .
   .
   .
}
function cargaSimilares() {
   let lip_cod = localStorage.getItem("codPROD");
   let lip_cat = localStorage.getItem("categoria").replaceAll(" ","_");
   let lip_subcat = localStorage.getItem("subcategoria").replaceAll(" ","_");
   let url = 'prdSimilares.php?lip_cod='+lip_cod+'lip_cat='+lip_cat+'lip_subcat='+lip_subcat;
   fetch(url)
   .then(response => response.json())
   .catch(error => console.error('Error: ',error);
   .then(response => console.log('Success: ',response));
}
```

y en el archivo prdSimilares.php tengo:

```
$lip_cod = $_GET['lip_cod'];
      $lip_cat = $_GET['lip_cat'];
      $lip_subcat = $_GET['lip_subcat'];
      echo json_encode($lip_cod);
      echo json_encode($lip_cat);
      echo json_encode($lip_subcat);
```

Comment: [Lee sobre la API fetch de Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch), es la mejor herramienta para hacer lo que quieres. Si de todos modos insistes en pasarlo con `window.open` debes poner en la URL los datos que quieres pasar y usar `$_GET` en el servidor para obtenerlos.

Comment: La forma de pasar datos en una URL sería esta: **`var url='http://producto.php?lip_cod='+cod_prd+'lip_cat='+categoria+'lip_subcat='+subcategoria;`** y luego: **`window.open(url,"_self");`** Luego en el servidor, debes verificar con GET para este caso, para verificar lo que se está recibiendo puedes hacer un: `var_dump($_GET);` y para obtener cada dato usa `$_GET` en todo en vez de `$_POST`, ya que ésta última se usa cuando los datos van en el `body` de la petición, y no es es el caso aquí. Si quieres mandar datos en el body debes usar ¡Fetchhhh o Ajax!.

Comment: @A.Cedano se necesita probar el envío de las variables en el servidor del dominio o puede ser en un servidor local ya que estoy usando xampp

Comment: Lo puedes probar en uno o en otro, no hay ningún problema en eso. Si es en local simplemente usas la URL del servidor local en vez de usar la URL del dominio remoto.

Comment: @A.Cedano estuve leyendo la documentación sobre ``fetch()`` y tengo unas dudas relacionadas justamente con la consulta que quiero realizar mediante php. Estas dudas son acerca de como leer las variables que voy a pasar desde la url ya que el mensaje de error que me manda el navegador es que las "variables son desconocidas" y por ende queda la solicitud con espacios en blanco y no se puede completar la búsqueda en la base de datos. PS: realice varios cambios los cuales van a verse en la pregunta.

Comment: Debes poner en la pregunta cómo estás implementando `fetch` y cómo estás leyendo los datos en PHP para que podamos ayudarte.

Comment: Si, justamente termine de actualizar la pregunta para que puedas ver los cambios que he realizado.

Comment: Si la petición fetch espera un JSON, tú debes garantizar siempre un JSON como respuesta en el servidor. No puedes resolver con un `echo "una cadena";`. Debes crear un array en todos los casos y devolver algo como `echo json_encode($elArray);` Además, no veo que leas los datos de la consulta SQL. Debes obtenerlos en forma de array. Por otro lado, no estás depurando bien. Pon tu petición así: `fetch(url). then(response => response.json()). catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))
 .then(response => console.log('Success:', response));` y dinos qué ves en la consola.

Comment: Y es que ni siquiera estoy seguro que tu petición `fetch` se esté enviando al servidor. La tienes en una función, pero no explicas cómo llamas a esa función. Pon un `alert('ok');` al inicio de la función y dinos si ves ese alert. Si lo ves, pues prueba a poner el `fetch` como te indiqué en mi anterior comentario y regulariza tu código PHP creando un array y haciendo echo de ese array con `json_decode`.  OJO: doy por supuesto que no estás MEZCLANDO `fecth` con `window.open`. Si vas a usar `fetch` olvídate de `window.open`. Son contradictorios y `fetch` es un avance enorme al respecto.

Comment: @A.Cedano; llamo a la función mediante el window.onload que me llama a una función en donde llamo a otra función que se encarga solamente de leer el archivo json y mostrar en el html. Hago de esta manera porque leí que solamente se puede ejecutar una función con window.onload y que si quiero que se ejecuten varias funciones al mismo tiempo tenía que crear otra función en donde se hace llamado a las otras funciones.

Comment: Window.open se encuentra en otra función por este motivo he trasladado lo que tenía entre las etiquetas de ``php`` de producto.php a prdSimilares.php

Comment: No entiendo mucho ese trabalengua. Además, window.onload no tendría sentido aquí, tú puedes englobar todo dentro del DOMContentLoaded, incluir aquellos archivos Javascript que necesites (si tuvieras varios archivos que gestionen cosas o reutilices) y hacer tu petición `fetch`. Yo creo que tienes un lío de conceptos y de organización de código que te está nublando todo y haciendo parecer como complicadísimo algo que es bastante sencillo. Pero si no te aclaras en los conceptos y explicas con la mayor claridad posible lo que tienes, cómo lo tienes ordenado y lo que quieres, es difícil ayudarte.

Comment: Y, lo mismo del lado de PHP. Tú NO NECESITAS window.open para incluir otros archivos PHP que requieras para gestionar tu petición `fetch`. Simplemente, puedes usar `include`  de PHP para incluir esos archivos en tu contexto de servidor. Es fundamental que entiendas que: Javascript trabaja del lado del cliente y de ese lado puedes incluir cualquier archivo Javascript, mientras que PHP trabaja del lado del servidor y de ese lado puedes incluir cualquier archivo que esté en el servidor. Y `fetch` sirve para comunicar entre cliente y servidor. Es tan simple como eso, no hay que hacerse tanto lío.

Comment: Por tanto, `window.open` NO SIRVE PARA NADA AQUÍ. Como ya dije, `fetch`  es un enorme avance en la comunicación cliente/servidor. Olvídate de `window.open` para este caso e incluye de cada lado todos aquellos archivos que necesites. No sé si me explico.

Comment: Te explico el funcionamiento de lo que tengo por el momento, al principio de todo tengo una pág. web donde me muestra todos los productos que tengo y allí esta enlazado el script que contiene la función clave() la cual tiene entre sus líneas de código inserciones a ``localStorage`` y el ``window.open("producto.php","_self")``;  una vez que se ejecuta es línea en el pág. producto.php que tiene enlazada el script con el ``window.onload = cargar() la cual entre las funciones que se ejecutan esta la función que lee otra información complementaria del producto y la función cargarSimilares()

Comment: Sugiero que expliques las cosas editando la pregunta. Te repito de nuevo, que **no tienes ninguna necesidad de `window.open`**, te puedes olvidar de él y gestionar todo con `fetch`. Es decir, en lugar de esto: `window.open("producto.php","_self")` tú puedes hacer una petición `fetch` dirigida a `producto.php` o a cualquier otro archivo en el servidor, enviar/traer/modificar datos en el servidor, recibir una respuesta en el cliente y modificar lo que quieras en localStorage o donde sea. Es decir, tú puedes hacer todo eso desde el mismo sitio sin tanto lío usando `fetch` **solamente**.

Comment: Listo, ya realice la explicación respectiva y ya lo pueden revisar

Comment: Es necesario tener instalado Node aún cuando ni lo he utilizado anteriormente?

Comment: Puedes hacer esto **también** con Node (en este caso bastaría Node), o bien con Javascript (usando Fetch o Ajax) y PHP (que es lo que tienes ahora y estás intentando), puedes comunicar entre cliente/servidor de una forma totalmente transparente, y actualizar cosas sin recargar la página y sin necesidad de Node. Son dos cosas distintas, que no tienen nada que ver una con la otra. [Node](https://nodejs.org/es/about/) es una herramienta totalmente distinta. Si te decides por Node puedes hacerlo, en ese caso no necesitarás PHP, pero tendrás que aprender Node, claro está.